# How to turn off code coverage for phpunit 5.4+

Tags: php, phpunit

In older versions of phpunit you could turn off code coverage reporting with the flag: `--no-coverage`. This allowed our suite to run much faster on CI environments, etc. In the current stable version (5.4) I don't see this option in [the docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions). What's the current way to turn off code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-coverage` option might be missing from the documentation but it works for me.

It's still in PHPUnit's code as well, see [Command.php:66](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.4.6/src/TextUI/Command.php#L66) and [Command.php:523](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.4.6/src/TextUI/Command.php#L523).

---

I've created a tiny test project with 1 class and 1 test to try it out. I've enabled code coverage output (HTML) in the [`<logging>`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging) section of *phpunit.xml*.

**Running phpunit without the option:**

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[removed irrelevant output]

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

Code coverage is being generated and outputted.

**Running phpunit with the option:**

```
$ phpunit --no-coverage
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[removed irrelevant output]

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

No code coverage generation. (The command ran faster too.)